# Steady state temperature distribution in a thin rectangular slab.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We need to solve the following :

$\nabla^{2} u =0 ,\:\:\:0<x<a$

$u(x,0) = f(x) , \:\:\: 0\leq x \leq a$

$u(x,b) = 0 ,\:\:\: 0\leq x \leq a$

$u_x (0,y) = 0 , \:\:\: u_x (a,y) =0$

We use separation of variables here and we let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y) \neq 0$.

Using this we get two equations : $ X^{''} - \lambda X = 0$ and $ Y^{''} + \lambda Y = 0$ which we solve for $ \lambda < 0 $ , taking $\lambda = - \alpha^{2} , \: \alpha >0$.

The solution of the first equation is found to be : $X_n (x) = A \cos (\frac{n\pi x}{a})$.

My problem is the other equation , solving which gives : $Y(y) = C \cosh(\alpha y) + D \sinh(\alpha y)$.

Applying the boundary condition gives : $ Y(b) = C \cosh(\alpha b) + D \sinh(\alpha b) = 0$. I couldn't proceed further. My text directly gives the combined solution as :

$ u(x,y) = (\frac{b-y}{b}) \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum a_n\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\sinh(\frac{n\pi }{a} (y-b))$.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sinh(\alpha y)$ where you have $\sin(\alpha y)$?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit that. Thanks !

Comment: It still says $\sin(\alpha b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Walk around to the other side of the slab; then the boundary conditions become $u(x,0) = 0$ and $u(x,b) = f(x)$, $0\le x\le a$. The solution $Y(y) = C\cosh(\alpha y) + D\sinh(\alpha y)$ must have $C=0$ due to the first boundary condition, so that the general solution is
$$u(x,y) = A_0 + \sum A_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}y\right).$$
Computing the coefficients using the Fourier series expansion, and resubstituting $b-y$ for $y$ gives the book's answer.

Comment: $C=0$ , that's okay. Thus $ Dsinh(\alpha y) =0$ , => $ sinh(\alpha y) =0$ => $ \alpha y = n \pi i$ , from where did $a$ came from ? Could you explain ?

Comment: You get, for each $\alpha_n = \frac{n\pi}{a}$, an eigenfunction $u_n(x,y) = A_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)\cdot D_n\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}y\right)$; collecting the constants and using the name $A_n$ for $A_nD_n$ gives the formula above.